# In python, will subprocess.call produce an individual subprocess every time being invoked?

Tags: python, subprocess

If subprocess.call is invoked N times, I wonder if N subprocess will be created or not.

And when will the subprocess close? Should I kill it manually?

What about subprocess.Popen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.call` creates a process every time it gets called and waits for the command to complete. So due to the nature of waiting for the command to finish there is no real parallel processing.

`subprocess.Popen` also creates a process every time it gets called, but does not wait for the command to complete. You can use `communicate` to wait for the command to complete or call `kill`.

So sum it up. With `subprocess.Popen` you have more control about the process you created.

Described in the  [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: If I just want to execute a command, os.system and subprocess.call which one is preferable?

Comment: Note that in python 3.5 there is a new **run** function that does the same sort of thing.

Comment: If you just want to execute a command and wait for it to complete `subprocess.call` should be fine ;)

Comment: @SteveBarnes You are right. I was not sure about the used python version

Comment: @salomonderossi Thanks. In my environment, python 2.7 is used.

Comment: @salomonderossi - it might be worth explicitly mentioning in your answer that since `call` waits there will only ever be one subprocess from a given python program at any point in time.

Comment: @sting_roc: `subprocess.call()` is essentially `subprocess.Popen().wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a new process is spawned every time you call `subprocess.call()` or any of its relatives, including `Popen()`.  You do not need to explicitly kill the subprocesses normally--you'd just wait for them to exit.